# How can I copy a number of photos off my G1 to my computer?

Tags: android

I have a number of photos stored in my G1 which I can view in the Gallery app. If I mount my phone to my computer over USB I'm able to brows folders but I can't find the photos anywhere. Are these photos stored on the SD card or the phone's internal memory? When I mount the phone to my computer over USB am I browsing the SD card or internal memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are in the DCIM folder and its subdirectories on the root of your SD card.

Answer (score 0):

(Unless you've rooted your phone) the G1 has no user accessible internal memory. All your photos, music, etc are on the SD card, and when you mount your phone to the computer over USB you're seeing the contents of your SD card.

As Crazysim says, you should be able to find your photos under the DCIM folder (same as you do for most digital cameras these days).